# Which mobile browsers has GPU acceleration for HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: mobile, cross-browser, html5-canvas

I'm searching for a very long time on the internet about browsers that support GPU acceleration for HTML5 Canvas. I know that Chrome on Android does (which is not the standard browser of Android). So I was wondering:

- Does the standard browser of Iphone/Ipad support GPU acceleration for Canvas?
- Ditto for the standard browser Android.
- Ditto for the Windows Phone.

And if yes, since which version is it implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell the following builds support GPU acceleration:

- iOS5 with Nitro Javascript
- Chrome for Android on Android4+ (default browser)
- Windows Phone 7 with IE9

Several articles confirmed this, [here's one](http://buildnewgames.com/mobile-game-primer/).